# How to deactivate and remove old site templates?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, site-template

I have created new site templates, which are meant to replace old templates. 
We want to deactivate and remove the old ones so only the new templates are available in template list.

I can deactivate and remove templates that have not been used yet. but when I try to deactivate old templates that have been used up until now, I get an error message saying

> I don't have access.

I have owner access to the site. Do I need to have Site Collection administrator rights to be able to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a permission issue, **The site Owner** can **only** deactivate and delete the `Site Template` that already not used.

At the other side, the `Site Collection Administrator` is responsible for the entire site collection and can deactivate and delete a `Site Template` that already used or not.

So you should be a `Site Collection Administrator` to be able to deactivate and delete `Site Template` that already used.

> **Note**: Once the site is saved as a template it saved in `Solution Gallery` below `Web Designer Galleries` in the Site Collection,
>   `Solution Gallery` is not available in sub site `Web Designer
>   Galleries`

---

**Site Owners** are responsible for one part of a Site Collection only, and cannot change anything on Site Collection level. They have full control on one or more subsites, and can grant permissions to users, create lists and subsite ... etc

**Site Collection Administrator:** is responsible for the entire site collection, has to access to Site Collection wide features in several places including Site Settings, Solutions Gallary ... etc.

Read more about [The difference between Site Owners and Site Collection Administrator](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/site-owner-vs-site-collection-administrator)

Comment: Thank you for  your reply. I had a suspition that that was the reason. I just neede confirmation :-)

Comment: Read also **[Full Reference: save site as template SharePoint Online and SharePoint Server](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-save-site-as-template-sharepoint-online/)**